# Eclipse/Java - "step over"-debugging not working, it skips static code

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm trying to debug an issues with my Java code using Eclipse STS, but it seems to me that the step into/over function skip lines in the static code blocks.

In the screenshot below, the debugger will hit the line with Breakpoint A (only if I set the breakpoint, I can't reach it by "step into"), but when I click step into/over, it will jump to Breakpoint B...I can't reach the lines between A and B (without setting additional breakpoints).

[image: screenshot]

Why is it, that I can't debug step through these lines?

I've only seen this for static code, but maybe it's a coincidence (I did try to restart Eclipse, clean the project, etc.)

Comment: Is this all local code that you are debugging? Or that comes from some external jars?